# Import C++ function into Python program

Tags: c++, python, function, import

I'm experimenting with python functions right now. I've found a way to import python functions into c/c++ code, but not the other way around.

I have a c++ program written and it has a certain function in it. I'd like to "import" the compiled c++ program into my python script and call the c++ function.

For simplicity, say the c++ function is as simple as:

```
int square(x)
{
  return x*x;
}
```

and the compiled program is named Cprog.

I'd like my python script to be something like:

```
import Cprog

print Cprog.square(4)
```

Is this possible? I've searched the internet to no avail and I'm hoping one of you gurus might have a clever way of going about this...

Comment: Have you tried Boost::Python?

Comment: No I haven't. But it looks like it might do what I want. I'm looking into it at the moment. Thanks a lot! Would anybody know of a less complicated way of doing this though (without the use of a third-wheel module)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling C/C++ from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)

Answer (score 30):

Here is a little working completion of the simple example above. Although the thread is old, I think it is helpful to have a simple all-embracing guide for beginners, because I also had some problems before.

function.cpp content (extern "C" used so that ctypes module can handle the function):

```
extern "C" int square(int x)
{
  return x*x;
}
```

wrapper.py content:

```
import ctypes
print(ctypes.windll.library.square(4)) # windows
print(ctypes.CDLL('./library.so').square(4)) # linux or when mingw used on windows
```

Then compile the function.cpp file (by using mingw for example):

```
g++ -shared -c -fPIC function.cpp -o function.o
```

Then create the shared object library with the following command (note: not everywhere are blanks):

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,library.so -o library.so function.o
```

Then run the wrapper.py an the program should work.

Comment: Tried this and got (WindowsError(126, 'The specified module could not be found'), <type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>) for the first one and ; 
(WindowsError(193, '%1 is not a valid Win32 application'), <type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>) for the second one. Any help?

Comment: @azazelspeaks Did you use `regsvr32.exe` to register that library?

Answer (score 11):

If you build your program as a shared library/DLL, you could use ctypes to call it.

```
import ctypes
print ctypes.windll.cprog.square(4) # windows
print ctypes.CDLL('cprog.so').square(4) # linux
```

Comment: I forgot about ctypes, definately the way to go if its just a couple of functions you want exposed.

Comment: What's the best way to create a *.so file? Sorry, I'm not a computer programmer/scientist, and my g++ command is usually along the lines of "g++ Ccode.cpp -o Cfile". I've tried using -shared as an additional option along with the linux line suggested above and I received an error. I don't think I've created my *.so file correctly...any advice?

Comment: @Nick: That's a different question, one that has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588476/building-a-shared-library-using-gcc

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a python module with that function in it. There are three main ways:

1. Using Swig - this reads your c code and creates a python module from it.
2. Hand coded using the python c api.
3. Using Boost::Python (often the easiest way).

[This pdf](http://www.swig.org/papers/PyTutorial98/PyTutorial98.pdf) covers 1 and 2. [This page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html) will tell you how to use Boost::Python.

You cannot (easily) use a function that is in a c/c++ program - it must be in a static library (which you can also link your c/c++ program against).

EDIT -
[Cython](http://www.cython.org/) Is also worth a mention.

Answer (score 4):

You want to **extend** python with a C/C++ module. The following Python documentation is a good place to start reading: http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to wrap C++ code to be used in Python. Most are listed on the Python wiki [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages#C.2BAC8-C.2B-.2B-).

I've found a decently easy way to automate it is to use [py++](http://www.language-binding.net/pyplusplus/pyplusplus.html) to automatically generate the wrappers, then compile the generated files. But this is more appropriate for larger projects where wrapping everything by hand is just not very feasible and would cause a maintenence nightmare.