# Shared Library not linking in functions

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, g++

I am building a Shared Library (.so) on Linux and I am compiling and linking in an object that is not dynamically linking in certain functions. These functions are "extern 'C'" functions. They are appearing in the normal symbol table of the shared object but not the external functions list or the dynamic functions list. I am compiling and linking using g++. I have turned off compiler optimizations. Is there special flag that needs to be set in order to get the functions to appear?

Edit:
The command I use to link the object files together is this:

```
g++ -m64 -rpath,/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/lib -shared -Wl,-soname,libQtCommercialChart.so.1 -o libQtCommercialChart.so.1.0.0 ../build/release/lib/chartdataset.o ../build/release/lib/chartpresenter.o ../build/release/lib/charttheme.o ../build/release/lib/domain.o ../build/release/lib/qchart.o ../build/release/lib/qchartview.o ../build/release/lib/qabstractseries.o ../build/release/lib/chartbackground.o ../build/release/lib/chartelement.o ../build/release/lib/scroller.o ../build/release/lib/chartlayout.o ../build/release/lib/versiontracker.o ../build/release/lib/axisanimation.o ../build/release/lib/xyanimation.o ../build/release/lib/pieanimation.o ../build/release/lib/piesliceanimation.o ../build/release/lib/splineanimation.o ../build/release/lib/baranimation.o ../build/release/lib/stackedbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/percentbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/abstractbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalstackedbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalpercentbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/areachartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qareaseries.o ../build/release/lib/chartaxis.o ../build/release/lib/qabstractaxis.o ../build/release/lib/chartvalueaxisx.o ../build/release/lib/chartvalueaxisy.o ../build/release/lib/qvalueaxis.o ../build/release/lib/chartbarcategoryaxisx.o ../build/release/lib/chartbarcategoryaxisy.o ../build/release/lib/qbarcategoryaxis.o ../build/release/lib/chartcategoryaxisx.o ../build/release/lib/chartcategoryaxisy.o ../build/release/lib/qcategoryaxis.o ../build/release/lib/chartdatetimeaxisx.o ../build/release/lib/chartdatetimeaxisy.o ../build/release/lib/qdatetimeaxis.o ../build/release/lib/bar.o ../build/release/lib/abstractbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qabstractbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/qbarset.o ../build/release/lib/qbarmodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qvbarmodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qhbarmodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/barchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qstackedbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/stackedbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qpercentbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/percentbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qhorizontalbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qhorizontalstackedbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalstackedbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qhorizontalpercentbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalpercentbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qlegend.o ../build/release/lib/legendmarker.o ../build/release/lib/legendlayout.o ../build/release/lib/linechartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qlineseries.o ../build/release/lib/qpieseries.o ../build/release/lib/piesliceitem.o ../build/release/lib/piechartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qpieslice.o ../build/release/lib/qpiemodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qvpiemodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qhpiemodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qscatterseries.o ../build/release/lib/scatterchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qsplineseries.o ../build/release/lib/splinechartitem.o ../build/release/lib/xychart.o ../build/release/lib/qxyseries.o ../build/release/lib/qxymodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qvxymodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qhxymodelmapper.o   -L/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/lib -L/tmp/qcharts/lib/release -Wl,-rpath,/tmp/qcharts/lib/release -lQtGui -L/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQtCore -lpthread
```

And the command used to build the the object with the missing functions is this:

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O0 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQTCOMMERCIALCHART_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/include/QtCore -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/include -I../include -I../include -I. -Ianimations -Iareachart -Iaxis -Iaxis/valueaxis -Iaxis/barcategoryaxis -Iaxis/categoryaxis -Iaxis/datetimeaxis -Ibarchart -Ibarchart/vertical/bar -Ibarchart/vertical/stacked -Ibarchart/vertical/percent -Ibarchart/horizontal/bar -Ibarchart/horizontal/stacked -Ibarchart/horizontal/percent -Ilegend -Ilinechart -Ipiechart -Iscatterchart -Isplinechart -Ithemes -Ixychart -I../build/release/lib -o ../build/release/lib/versiontracker.o versiontracker.cpp
```

Comment: Lets see your `g++` command and the errors you're getting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3588476/1741542 is a comprehensive question about building shared libraries with gcc.

Comment: @Olaf: That's not "comprehensive" -- that's a fracking mess!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Superior references are always welcome :-)

Comment: @Olaf: Attempting to read that "question" has irrevocably broken my reference-gathering skills for the evening

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I hope you'll recover soon. And my apologies for this devastating suggestion ;-)

Comment: You appear to be using `-fvisibility=hidden`. I wonder what this flag does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`man gcc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)

> **-fvisibility**=default|internal|hidden|protected
>   ...
>   **extern** declarations are not affected by **-fvisibility**, so a lot of code can be recompiled with **-fvisibility=hidden** with no modifications. However, this means that calls to **extern** functions with no explicit visibility will use the PLT , so it is more effective to use **__attribute ((visibility))** and/or **#pragma GCC visibility** to tell the compiler which **extern** declarations should be treated as hidden.

I haven't used this myself, but from [GCC Wiki - Visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) and a small example, I would say that adding

```
__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
```

to your `extern "C"` functions, should make them visible in the dynamic functions list, e.g. `nm -D libQtCommercialChart.so.1.0.0`.

If you have many functions defined, bracing them with

```
extern "C" {
#pragma GCC visibility push(default)
...
#pragma GCC visibility pop
};
```

might be more convenient.

If you don't care about symbol visibility, dropping `-fvisibility=hidden` from your command line will work as well, of course.