# Build .so file from .c file using gcc command line

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a hello world project for Linux dynamic libraries (.so files). So I have a file hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void hello()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

How do I create a .so file that exports `hello()`, using gcc from the command line?

Answer (score 412, accepted):

To generate a shared library you need first to compile your C code with the `-fPIC` (position independent code) flag.

```
gcc -c -fPIC hello.c -o hello.o
```

This will generate an object file (.o), now you take it and create the .so file:

```
gcc hello.o -shared -o libhello.so
```

**EDIT**: Suggestions from the comments:

You can use

```
gcc -shared -o libhello.so -fPIC hello.c
```

to do it in one step. – [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)

I also suggest to add `-Wall` to get all warnings, and `-g` to get debugging information, to your `gcc` commands. – [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch)

Comment: Or `gcc -shared -o libhello.so -fPIC hello.c` to do it in one step.