# How can i make so file from header file and c files?

Tags: c, linux

I have  some c files and .h header files .now I have to make .so file from this .c and .h file how can I do this?

Comment: Visit [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884126/build-so-file-from-c-file-using-gcc-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
```