# How to generate a .so file

Tags: linux, gtk, gnome, vala

I am writing an extension for the Scratch text editor application on Elementary OS Luna. But the documentation is practically non-existent for extension creation and I have no idea how to proceed after writing my main code for the extension.

I've already written the extension. I cannot use or test it yet as it needs to be "installed". I spent hours looking for docs but they do not exist. I did however, find a comment on the scratch launchpad page that says

> Generally you have to generate a pluginname.so file and put it in
>   lib/scratch/plugins/pluginname with a pluginname.plugin file

Great. This seems like the last part of creating an extension for Scratch. What is a .so file, and how do I generate one? I've already created the other necessary files like the .plugin file and the .vala file.

Yes, I have searched for .so files but all I found were random things about it like using it with  C, or C++ headers but obviously that won't work for me, since I'm using Vala?

How do I generate a .so file? What do I generate it from?

Comment: It's not random! You write the extension in a language that generates a .so file (like C/C++ etc) and then you use it in your scratch app. See this q/a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809213/what-are-a-and-so-files

Comment: @PreetSangha Thank you for the link :-) Btw, are .so files basically like DLL's in Windows?

Comment: Do you have any other resources? I have no idea what that page is saying :(

Comment: yes you're correct. To address you're question. The [link](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) in that page shows how they can be created using GCC for example. But you still have to write the code. A question for you would be to enhance your question with some links that have describing what you've followed. Maybe someone can see something that you need to do.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, @PreetSangha. I am back now and am looking at your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [The Vala tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Libraries) could be helpful on creating the actual **Shared library** or **Shared Object**.

You can use the `autotools`, `cmake` or you can compile and link a shared library directly from the command line, quoted from the Vala tutorial:

> Compilation and linking using Command Line
>
> Vala is not yet capable of directly creating dynamic or static
>   libraries. To create a library, proceed with the -c (compile only)
>   switch and link the object files with your favourite linker, i.e.
>   libtool or ar.
>
> ```
> $ valac -c ...(source files) 
> $ ar cx ...(object files)
> ```
>
> or by compiling the intermediate C code with gcc
>
> ```
> $ valac -C ...(source files) 
> $ gcc -o my-best-library.so --shared -fPIC ...(compiled C code files)...
> ```

Comment: Thank you @user, I will look into this. It looks promising! :-D +1

Answer (score 1):

From the [Scratch Wiki](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/w/images/ExtensionsDoc.HTTP-9-11.pdf)

> Due to browser security restrictions, Scratch 2.0 cannot interact with
>   hardware devices directly. Instead, hardware extensions come with a
>   helper app, a separate application that the user must install and run
>   on their computer. Scratch communicates with the helper app via HTTP
>   requests, and the helper app talks to the hardware. In the future,
>   some extensions may package their helper apps as browser plugins.
>
> Here are the steps for creating and testing a Scratch extension:
>
> 1. Create an extension description file
> 2. Create your helper app and start it
> 3. Open the Scratch 2 Offline Editor
> 4. Import the extension description (shift-click on "File" and select "Import Experimental  Extension" from the menu)
> 5. The new extension blocks will appear in the More Blocks palette
> 6. Test your extension and iterate!
>
> **Helper apps can be written in any language that supports server sockets, such as Python, Node.js,  Java, C, etc.**

Like you I've chased around the wiki but I cannot find an example with source. So all I  can do is to address your question generally.

If you look at [Build .so file from .c file using gcc command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884126/build-so-file-from-c-file-using-gcc-command-line) you'll see how a simple .so can be created. However what code goes into a Scratch extension I don't know. Sorry.

Edit: More googling and I've found [a sample from Nathan Dinsmore on GitHub that doesn't use C rather it uses JavaScript](https://github.com/nathandinsmore/scratchext), and though it doesn't create a .so extension, it does have what appears to be a full description of creating an extension. He also provides a couple of [tutorials](https://github.com/nathandinsmore/scratchext/wiki).

Edit++ : [And here is another sample written in Java](https://github.com/MrYsLab/CodeShield_Scratch_Extension).

Comment: I think we are talking about two different things here. The Scratch Wiki you linked to seems to be for something other than the Scratch Text Editor. I think what you linked to is for the Scratch programming language. And the samples you linked to are extensions for the scratch language. I think that's what's so confusing to me; there are no resources for _making extensions **for** the Scratch Text Editor_.

Comment: There are two Scratch's. There's the Scratch Text Editor that comes with the Linux Distribution Elementary OS and then there's Scratch; a programming language. I am looking for resources for the former.

Comment: I can not use the information contained within those pages you linked to because to create a Scratch extension (which are written in Vala not C or C++) you do not create executable files, you just save them as .vala files. And that tutorial relies on executable files. I have followed the tutorial but it's not possible to generate a .so file because I have no executable (you don't create executables for Scratch text editor extensions)

Comment: Ok I see my my mistake, and I suspect I should have waited until you'd put links to the actual 'Scratch' you were referring to. C'est la Vie! Ok should I delete this answer?