# How to compile Java native library?

Tags: java, android, c++

I hope that's the right word to use, "compile." I'm asking here since I'm not even sure what to Google for to get more information.

I want to use this library here: http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/#gifflen

The download gives a bunch of .cpp and .h files. From what I understand, I need a .so file in order to use `System.loadLibrary(libName)`.

What I can't figure out is how to compile these C++ files into the necessary .so file?

Comment: Try `g++ mylibrary.cpp -o mylibrary.so -shared -fPIC`.

Comment: Btw that's not a "Java native library", it's a "native library".

Comment: @KerrekSB Alright, so I went and downloaded/installed MinGW and ran the command above. It worked. However, now when I attempt to use the library, I get **Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform**. How can I go about resolving this, any parameters I need or something?

Comment: @FTLRalph: Add `-m64` maybe?

Comment: @KerrekSB Figured it out. I had downloaded MinGW 64 and updated by PATH variable, but didn't reboot. Was still building off of the old compiler. All good now, thanks!

Comment: No worries, though if your operating system requires you to reboot in order to update an environment variable, perhaps that says something about your operating system... :-S

Answer (score 3):

You can create shared object file using below mentioned command.

```
gcc -shared -fpic -o <so-file-name>.so a.c b.c
```

**on Mac OS X, compile with:**

```
g++ -dynamiclib -flat_namespace myclass.cc -o myclass.so
g++ class_user.cc -o class_user
```

**On Linux, compile with:**

```
g++ -fPIC -shared myclass.cc -o myclass.so
g++ class_user.cc -ldl -o class_user
```

**References:**

[C++ Dynamic Shared Library on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496664/c-dynamic-shared-library-on-linux)

[Build .so file from .c file using gcc command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884126/build-so-file-from-c-file-using-gcc-command-line)

[Sample tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)

**Sample code to run .so file using java with commands:**

**HelloJNI.c**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloJNI.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return;
}
```

**HelloJNI.java**

```
public class HelloJNI {
   static {
      System.loadLibrary("hello"); // hello.dll (Windows) or libhello.so (Unixes)
   }
   // A native method that receives nothing and returns void
   private native void sayHello();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new HelloJNI().sayHello();  // invoke the native method
   }
}
```

**Steps to run above .c file using .java file**

```
javac HelloJNI

javah HelloJNI

gcc -shared -fpic -o libhello.so -I/usr/java/default/include -I/usr/java/default/include/linux HelloJNI.c

java  -Djava.library.path=. HelloJNI
```

Comment: Note that javah was deprecated in Java 8: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/313