# call C code from Python via ctypes, use python object list

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes

I want to

1. write a function `sum_list` of sum a list in c, named sum_list.c
2. make the `sum_list.c` file to sum_list.so
3. `sum_list = ctypes.CDLL('./sum_list.so')`
4. `result = sum_list.sum_list([1, 2, 3])`

It raise error in step 4:

> ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: : Don't know how
>   to convert parameter 1

when I write a function in c which add two numbers, it works ok.

so, the point is i don't know how to pass a list (python object) to c.

---

**sum_list.c**

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

long sum_list(PyObject *list)
{
    Py_ssize_t i, n;
    long total = 0, value;
    PyObject *item;

    n = PyList_Size(list);
    if (n < 0)
        return -1; /* Not a list */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        item = PyList_GetItem(list, i); /* Can't fail */
        if (!PyLong_Check(item)) continue; /* Skip non-integers */
        value = PyLong_AsLong(item);
        if (value == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())
            /* Integer too big to fit in a C long, bail out */
            return -1;
        total += value;
    }
    return total;
}
```

---

**python code**

```py
from ctypes import CDLL

sum_list = CDLL('./sum_list.so')

l = [1, 2, 3]
sum_list.sum_list(l)
```

> **I expect the `var` result in my python code is `6`.**

Comment: `PyList_GetItem(list, i); /* Can't fail */` is actually false. [It can fail](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L244) - especially if the list changes size for some reason during the iteration. It might be hard to deduce that it doesn't!

Comment: And if it does fail, your code will too.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I think i understand the reason... I copy the code from https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#coding-standards  can you show some 
brief demo of how the address passing can possible?

Comment: @kun Please, don't forget to come back and upvote/accept answers that were helpful to you. That's how we say "thank you" around here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ctypes library is meant for calling functions in pure C libraries. The example that you found is for a function that would go into a Python extension module, and be usable without ctypes. Ctypes actually has a type for `PyObject *`, namely `ctypes.py_object`. You need to wrap the list in this - be careful to ensure that it will stay alive!

In any case you must almost always provide the correct prototype of the function using the `restype` and `argtypes`.

Here's a working example:

```
import ctypes

sum_list = ctypes.PyDLL('./sum_list.so')
sum_list.restype = ctypes.c_long
sum_list.argtypes = [ ctypes.py_object ]

l = [1, 2, 3]
print(sum_list.sum_list(ctypes.py_object(l)))
```

**Note**, as noticed by Mark, you must use [`PyDLL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.PyDLL) here instead, to ensure that the GIL is *not* released since the function does not acquire it!

Comment: `CDLL` releases the GIL.  Make sure to use `PyDLL` if the function uses Python C APIs.

Comment: @MarkTolonen fixed. It shows that I've never done this ;)

Comment: Esoteric stuff :^)

Comment: thanks! use C in python are so different than I imagine.

Answer (score 2):

I've up-voted @Antii's answer, but still wanted to add a short, complete, and self-contained example.

First, `ctypes` is to interact with C code that was written without Python interoperability in mind. Generally, this means code that does not `#include <Python.h>` and so on. For example:

```
/**
 * Sample function to call from Python 3
 * Build:
 *  $ gcc -shared -o libmath.so -fPIC math.c
 *
 * See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14884166/4594973
 *
 **/
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

While the code above is trivial, you need to make sure that more complicated pieces of code are compiled properly. For example, if you're using a C++ comnpiler and/or are using features specific to C++ (e.g. classes, method overloading, etc), then you ***must*** expose a C-compatible interface when building the library, as C++'s name mangling will make it next to impossible to find the function after the fact.

After building the C code above, use this Python script to call it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ctypes

cmath = ctypes.CDLL('./libmath.so')
cmath.restype = ctypes.c_int
cmath.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]

x = 4
y = 5
r = cmath.add(x, y)

print(f'{x} + {y} = {r}')
```

Running the samples from my terminal:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libmath.so -fPIC math.c
$ python3 math.py
4 + 5 = 9
```

Comment: BTW, the `c` in my sample `cmath` library here stands for cheap ._.

Comment: I think I should consider this problem in a new way, in a C way maybe!

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer mentioned, you can use `ctypes.py_object` to represent an actual Python object, but you must also remember when calling Python C APIs you must not release the GIL (global interpreter lock).  Use `PyDLL` instead of `CDLL` to accomplish this.

Here's a fully working example that works for sequences in general:

**test.c**

```
#include <Python.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    define API
#endif

API long sum_list(PyObject* o)
{
    Py_ssize_t i, n;
    long total = 0, value;
    PyObject* list;
    PyObject* item;

    list = PySequence_Fast(o,"not a sequence");  // New reference!  Must DECREF eventually.
    if(list == NULL)
        return -1;
    n = PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(list);
    for (i = 0; i < PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(list); i++) {
        item = PySequence_Fast_GET_ITEM(list, i);
        if (!PyLong_Check(item))
        {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"sequence contains non-integer");
            Py_DECREF(list);
            return -1;
        }
        value = PyLong_AsLong(item);
        if (value == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())
        {
            Py_DECREF(list);
            return -1;
        }
        total += value;
    }
    Py_DECREF(list);
    return total;
}
```

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *

dll = PyDLL('test')
dll.sum_list.restype = c_long
dll.sum_list.argtypes = py_object,

print(dll.sum_list((1,2,3,4,5)))
try:
    print(dll.sum_list(7))
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
try:
    print(dll.sum_list((1,2,'a',4,5)))
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
try:
    print(dll.sum_list((1,2,0x80000000,4,5)))
except OverflowError as e:
    print(e)
try:
    print(dll.sum_list((1,2,-0x80000001,4,5)))
except OverflowError as e:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
15
not a sequence
sequence contains non-integer
Python int too large to convert to C long
Python int too large to convert to C long
```