# Difference between shared library (.so) a Linux executable file without extension?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, executable

To clarify, this is a question about binary Linux executables, not scripts, which can also be executable and also often lack an extension.

In my experience, most Linux binary executables lack a file extension; e.g. most of the files in the `/bin` directory on Linux systems lack an extension.

On the other hand, most of the files in the `/lib` directory have `.so` in their file extension, and also have executable permissions. Trying to execute an `.so` file directly usually results in seg fault or some error, which makes sense because shared libraries are usually intended to be dynamically linked. But as I understand it, if the `.so` file has a `main()` entrypoint, then [you can run it as an executable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223385/why-and-how-are-some-shared-libraries-runnable-as-though-they-are-executables) as you would a normal executable (i.e. a file without an extension).

My questions:

1. What is the difference between a shared library (`.so` extension) and an executable file (`[none]` extension)? Is it just whether a `main()` entrypoint is defined?
2. In C++, is there any difference (i.e. flags passed to the compiler) in compiling code into a shared library (`.so` extension) and compiling code into a Linux executable (`[none]` extension).

Edit: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884126/build-so-file-from-c-file-using-gcc-command-line) talks about how to build an .so file using gcc command line, but doesn't identify the differences between building an .so versus a normal executable.

Comment: You can read [ELF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and [Build .so file from .c file using gcc command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884126/build-so-file-from-c-file-using-gcc-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One of the main differences is that a shared library does not have a `main()` function. It also contains position independent code that may or may not be the case for executables. If you *do* put a `main()` function in the library, you still need to link it with a *normal* object file (containing *no* `main()` function).
2. Yes. To create a shared library you compile your code with [`-fpic` or `-fPIC`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options) to generate position-independent code (*PIC*) suitable for use in a shared library.

Nothing prevents you from creating an executable called `myexe.so` though, but it can't be used as a shared library.

Comment: Afaik, nowadays executables are also position independent by default (at least on x86-64 without explicit `-no-pie` option) to support address space layout randomization. For example, on my machine, `gcc -v` outputs: `Target: x86_64-linux-gnu Configured with: ... --enable-default-pie ...`.

Comment: @Evg I see. On my system it's not (`Target: x86_64-redhat-linux`), but I made a note about it in the answer.